# Is stuffing keywords into the bottom of my page going to hurt my SEO or help my site rank for those keywords?

Tags: seo, keywords, keyword-stuffing

[image]

I trying to get most visitors in least effort and least money.
Does spamming on site like this improves search results
I see lots of site use that get boosted in very high in results the drop on result after like a month
I using a domain going to expire in a month even though site gets blacklisted on google just getting a small community is enought then moving everyone to new site

Comment: No, this does not help your rankings and almost certainly hurts it. Search engines saw through this trick over decades ago. (At least the ones that survived). It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way this works in 2021. You should focus on producing good content and making your website fast and responsive. Otherwise you may just end up with a penalty from Google that you can't reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this text content by adding "hidden" style to content div. This will not shown in users view but it can be read by search engines.

```
<div style="display:none">
<!-- insert your hidden contents here -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but does its effective i saw some sites but they had very long text (about 5 k lines so) to get barely on second result on google if theres any shorter alternative way of doing this (and not ruining user exerince obiviously)